# Is there a difference between a component and a module

Tags: design, architecture

I have a little problem with the terms module and component.
In my mind, a module are bundled classes, which are only accesable via a well defined interface. They hide all implementation details and are reusable. Modules define modules on which they depend.

What is the difference to components? I looked it up in some books, but the description of components is very similar.

Comment: Which language? Which architecture? Your definition of module works. I think of a component as something that plugs into something for say a GUI while a module can not plug into a GUI; modules can work in a GUI if wrapped/supported by GUI constructs.

Comment: See [Class vs. Component vs. Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b(v=vs.71).aspx) Note: I am not answering because your question does not mention langauge or architecture.

Comment: Yes, in this case, I think about the definitions in general

Comment: I am not after points, more after making sure you get a valid answer. If you find this valid, then feel free to edit your question and add the link as the answer you prefer. I will not post it as an answer because the question is too general and a specific answer can get others into trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I think my question is very general and the answer really depends on the used language or enviornement. Nerver thought there are so much different definitions for these terms

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The terms are similar. I generally think of a "module" as being larger than a "component". A component is a single part, usually relatively small in scope, possibly general-purpose. Examples include UI controls and "background components" such as timers, threading assistants etc. A "module" is a larger piece of the whole, usually something that performs a complex primary function without outside interference. It could be the class library of an application that provides integration with e-mail or the database. It may be as large as a single application of a suite, such as the "Accounts Receivable module" of an ERP/accounting platform.

I also think of "modules" as being more interchangeable. Components can be replicated, with new ones looking like old ones but being "better" in some way, but typically the design of the system is more strictly dependent upon a component (or a replacement designed to conform to that component's very specific behavior). In non-computer terms, a "component" may be the engine block of a car; you can tinker within the engine, even replace it entirely, but the car must have an engine, and it must conform to very rigid specifications such as dimensions, weight, mounting points, etc in order to replace the "stock" engine which the car was originally designed to have. A "module", on the other hand, implies "plug-in"-type functionality; whatever that module is, it can be communicated with in such a lightweight way that the module can be removed and/or replaced with minimal effect on other parts of the system. The electrical system of a house is highly modular; you can plug anything with a 120V15A plug into any 120V15A receptacle and expect the thing you're plugging in to work. The house wiring couldn't care less what's plugged in where, provided the power demands in any single branch of the system don't exceed safe limits.

Comment: All answers really helped me, but I can only accept one. So I accept KeithS's because he has the lowest rep

Answer (score 22):

## Abstract software granularity hierarchy

If we are to abstract from particular languages, frameworks and their own interpretations, the abstract software granularity hierarchy is the following:

```
Product - application, library, service
  Module - GUI, core logic, data, etc...
    Component - purpose specific collection of objects
      Object - collection of primitives
        Primitive - numbers, functions, etc...
```

## Product

Plain and simple, the Product is a working collection of connected functional modules.

## Module

As the very name implies, the motivation of a Module is modularity. Contrary to what many claim, it does not really imply code reuse. There are many modules which are not really reusable, and don't fit with anything they were not designed to.

It is important to separate different software layers, that makes software much easier to implement and maintain, and should the need to reimplement something like a front end to a different GUI framework, modularity enables that to happen in an easy and safe manner, without breaking code all over the place.

A module encapsulates a collection of components which all serve a common purpose as defined by the module requirements. A module should be self-contained and complete, and while not really usable on its own, it should be able to work in conjunction with any conforming implementation.

## Component

In terms of granularity the Component sits between the Module and the Object. The purpose of a component is to put together a collection of general purpose objects to form a purpose specific unit.

As the name implies, unlike the Module, the Component is not "self-contained", it is a part of a larger functional whole.

## Object

Objects are the smaller building blocks of components. Objects are collections of primitives and couple them together to serve a lower level, more universal while still somewhat specific purpose.

## Primitive

Primitives are the smallest, simplest and lowest level of software development granularity. It's basically just integer and real numbers and functions/operators, although most languages have their own additional "first class citizens".

There is very little you can do with primitives, and at the same time, it is at a such a low level that you can accomplish practically everything with it. It is just very, very verbose, insanely complicated and impossibly tedious to accomplish while directly working with primitives.

## What's the point of all this?

As already mentioned above, working with primitives directly is an extremely bad idea. Not only because it is impossibly complex, slow and tedious to do for modern day software development, but it is also extremely obtrusive and obstructive to testing and maintenance.

Having all of those conceptual parts incorporated into software development makes it easier, faster, simpler and safer. You don't make a house out of atoms, regardless of how versatile and universal atoms are. That would be an exercise in futility. Your atoms are your primitives, clay is your object, bricks are your components, walls, floor and roof are your modules, assembled together they manifest the final product.

Humans don't really invent anything, we only discover things already out there in the universe, and then copy and apply them to our lives. The same granularity hierarchy is intrinsic to the universe itself, from atoms and even below, to organic molecules, proteins, tissues, organs, organisms and above, reality itself obeys the same principle - combining small, simple, function limited and purpose abstract things into larger, more complex, more functional things and more purpose specific things.

## Terminology caveats

Technically they are all "objects", they are all "components" of software development, they are all "modular" enough to be able to fit together, they are all "products" in the sense that they have been produced and so on...

This is not about terminology or nomenclature, it is about how scaling things up and out affects various aspects of creativity and productivity. And about the importance of not only using all those different levels, but also the importance of not trying to accomplish a goal at the wrong level, which can only be counterproductive.

Comment: Your version of module sounds like a package.

Comment: @J.M.Becker not really, in terms of granularity a package can consist of anything from a collection of objects to a full standalone product. Packaging is more of a convenience thing for code reuse than a link in the granularity chain.

Comment: If we're talking about from the perspective of a product and/or project, a component has runtime implications, and its also self-contained.  It's self-contained so that you avoid the inherent fragility that is a totally centralized and shared development between diffrent teams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering

Comment: Objects are one way to organize code, modules are about organizing a collection of code under a namespace with publicly accessible parts defined via exports.   Components are about organizing parts of a running product. Packages are about distribution.  There is also libraries... know what, much of this isn't hierarchical, it is orthogonal with overlap depending on context.  An Object which organizes code, and is used as an object when programming, BUT which has the runtime characteristics of a component.... is both concepts at once, a Component Object.

Comment: It is hierarchical and that hierarchy is purpose and functionality based, you are just not seeing that due to confusing the words by applying pre-existing, non conceptually structured definitions to them, that was already stated in the last couple of paragraphs. In my software architecture, components come with dynamism, reflection, scoping and structuring and other facilities that make sense to be coarsely grained and it makes programming and using much faster and easier, but would constitute too much overhead if available for every object as is the case for most high level dynamic languages.

Comment: I'm not saying the concepts cannot be implemented hierarchically, but only that the concepts themselves are not inherently hierarchical.

Comment: And what I am saying is understanding, establishing and using said hierarchy is key to creating quality software :) It is a "right tool for the job" thing. Aside from that, words are just words, what they actually convey is down to the context.

Comment: Your articles contributes the important aspect of how to apply these concepts in practical management. But, after reading a couple of other articles, I ask myself if an important correction of your hierarchy might be needed. Consider that a module is (very often) about a name-space and independence, not about interfaces, while components should have [clearly definied interfaces](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modul_(Software)):

Comment: Isn't the module then a (loose) collection of objects (in the same name-space), while components bundle and deliver modules together with an interface contract, switching their positions?

Comment: @Make42 Composition is up to the developer, it is fairly arbitrary what you can put in what. This is about what is bigger and what is smaller, which in turn determines what tool is fit for what task. When I picked a word for each level, I didn't that much bother with borrowing from anyone's existing terminology than really ask myself what makes sense conceptually. You are not switching positions of things, just the names. Clearly defined interfaces are not exclusive to any of the elements I outline, those are intrinsic to good design. Even primitives have CDIs, that's how they are useful.

Comment: The actual computer case + internals is a component of a computer system, together with its display and IO peripherals. The motherboard is a computer component as well. As is every microchip on the motherboard. As is every transistor in each chip. And the element Si is a component of each functional transistor. I'd say that the Si is the primitive here, a transistor is an object, a chip is a component, the mobo is the module, and the case + internals is the product. A computer can work in this form, without user I/O. A monitor however is just a module, it is not useful on its own.

Comment: I suppose growing up with electronics has made an impact on me in the context of component vs module. As far as I can remember myself, I've known discrete electronic components, going onto boards with connectors that constitute various modules of the whole electronic machine. So what is the rationale for switching those two? Mind you a lot of the existing nomenclature is outdated legacy from a very different computing era that doesn't, at least IMO, make a lot of sense in the context of contemporary software development.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the term module belongs to architectural design and component to the implementation?

Answer (score 15):

The generic meaning of *module* is a group of reusable code, not tied to one specific program.  This could be everything from an entire set of GUI libraries down to a single class.

The generic meaning of *component* is a module with the additional restriction of substitutability using a specific interface.  If you create a GUI Widget component, it can be used anywhere a Widget is expected, without having to do anything special in the calling code.    Modules in general have no such restriction.  Qt and GTK+ are modules, but I can't swap out one for the other without considerable work in the code calling it, therefore they are not components.

Many frameworks or programming languages use the terms to mean something much more specific, which is why people are asking about context.  Something may be a component in the generic sense, but if it doesn't implement a very specific `IComponent` interface, it may not be considered a component in context.  In python, `module` has the very specific technical meaning of something you can get using an `import` command.  Usually people are referring to these context-specific meanings.

Comment: Your definition is fine, but your example (Qt vs. GTK+) is flawed (though I agree that I would not call any of them a component, too). IMHO Qt and GTK+ both contain hundreds of small components, thus resulting in a very broad collection of interfaces. That makes it very unlikely that someone will ever invest the time to create an interface compatible replacement for one of them, and *that* is IMHO the reason why they are no components. However, just because two pieces of software cannot be interchanged does not disqualify them as components, only as components with a common interface.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your context. Module is already used to refer to DLL level groups in some languages, akin to 'package' or 'assembly' in others. Component is used for COM things as well as Entity Based Component stuff common in game development.

In general architectural terms, module and component do both tend to refer to some bundle of code behind a well defined interface. In general, module tends to refer to larger bundles. There's often a set of interfaces and the module tends to be able to stand on its own.

Components on the other hand tend to be smaller bundles of code, often smaller than a full class. By their name, they tend to be a component of something larger. Sometimes that is the application itself, but with the increasing usage of composition in class design it more often means a component of a larger object. The well defined interfaces for components also tends to allow the app to swap components in for each other. Modules tend not to have that swapability.