# What is a not well-defined interface?

Tags: microservices, interfaces

I keep reading about "well defined interfaces", as [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178927/is-there-a-difference-between-a-component-and-a-module/372825), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340220/java-interfaces-in-layers-pattern/361244) or [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274711/does-modular-programming-refer-to-modules-or-programs), specially when talking about [microservices](https://www.oreilly.com/radar/modules-vs-microservices/).

What's an example of the opposite, an interface that is **not** well-defined?

Comment: Please make your question self contained (i.e. cite from the articles you have linked).

Comment: This is a good topic.  But πάντα ῥεῖ  is correct. We don't support link only questions. See also [discuss this blog](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog).

Comment: The links aren't necessary to understand the question. They are just in support of the claim.

Comment: "whatever the server actually does"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any interface definition that isn't specific enough to determine whether a client or service implementation conforms to it is not well-defined. Some examples:

- unspecified character encoding (one side using utf-8 while the other uses iso8859-1)
- unspecified number representation (decimal point versus comma)
- implicit sequencing requirements (need to call `createFooList` before you can call `addFoo`)
- incomplete specification of limits, constraints, semantic rules etc.

In general, if developers argue about the correct usage or implementation of an interface it's a good indicator that the interface is ill-defined (or that the developers didn't understand it, which also happens.)

Just being awkward or difficult to use doesn't make an interface ill-defined, though.

Comment: ... It makes ammending the interfaces definition to get it well-defined if even possible much more difficult though. And especially for the last part, +1